# Kubernetes: what proxy-mode does the NodePort type use?

Tags: proxy, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

When I am using NodePort type to expose service in kubernetes, what proxy-mode does it use?

Comment: When a deployment is exposed with source IP for service type set to NodePort, ProxyMode can not be used due to how traffic is being handled see [doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/services/source-ip/#source-ip-for-services-with-type-nodeport) on source IP for services with Type=NodePort for more details. If you want to use Proxy-mode, check ClusterIP; because Kube-proxy  exposes its mode through a proxyMode endpoint because of the way it handles traffic see this [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/services/source-ip/#source-ip-for-services-with-type-clusterip)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a deployment is exposed with source IP for service type set to NodePort, ProxyMode can not be used due to how traffic is being handled see doc on source IP for services with Type=NodePort for more details.

If you want to use Proxy-mode, check ClusterIP; because Kube-proxy exposes its mode through a proxyMode endpoint because of the way it handles traffic see this [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/services/source-ip/#source-ip-for-services-with-type-clusterip)